# Add Retry Policy V2 Model Python Service Bus Queue Trigger

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-queues

I have created an Azure Service Bus Queue with terraform, it is deployed and working properly.
I want to add a retry delay for the queue.
I have added following line in Python V2 model but after deployment it breaks and my function disappears from the Azure function tab

```
@app.retry(strategy="fixed_delay", delay_interval="00:00:10")
@app.service_bus_queue_trigger(arg_name="azservicebus", queue_name="publish-queue", connection="SERVICE_BUS_CONNECTION",
)
def publish_der(azservicebus: func.ServiceBusMessage):
"""Service bus trigger which receives data from API"""
//implementation goes here
```

What is the proper way to add re try for Python v2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use retry option in Azure Function Service bus V2 Model you need to use retry option in **`host.json`** in local:

```
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "retry": {
    "strategy":"fixedDelay",
    "maxRetryCount": 5,
    "delayInterval":"00:00:30"
  },
  "logging": {
    "applicationInsights": {
      "samplingSettings": {
        "isEnabled": true,
        "excludedTypes": "Request"
      }
    }
  },
  "extensionBundle": {
    "id": "Microsoft.Azure.Functions.ExtensionBundle",
    "version": "[4.*, 5.0.0)"
  }
}
```

My **`functionapp.py`**:

```
import azure.functions as func
import logging

app = func.FunctionApp()

@app.service_bus_queue_trigger(arg_name="azservicebus", queue_name="mysbqueue",
                               connection="testjkafka_SERVICEBUS") 
def servicebus_queue_trigger(azservicebus: func.ServiceBusMessage):
    raise Exception("Simulated failure")
    logging.info('Python ServiceBus Queue trigger processed a message: %s',
                azservicebus.get_body().decode('utf-8'))
```

Then when I deployed I can see my function:

[image]

Comment: So If I have multiple queue triggers and I want to define a different delay, how would that work?

Comment: In local create triggers in a single project and then for all triggers if there is  one host.json file then it will be applicable to all. Try that and test

Comment: so different retry schedule will require multiple projects, right?

Comment: Yeah, that is my understanding.

Comment: I have tried that configuration, I can see delay of 30 seconds but it re tries 10 times (configured on queue level) but in the config it is mentioned 5 times.

Comment: Not sure why, as i have got only 5 times